# Permission denied (publickey), on Linux AWS server can i fix it?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, vpn

I got a free tier on aws Linux server which is supposed to work but I get the following error:

```
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0555 for 'vpnserver.pem' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
Load key "vpnserver.pem": bad permissions
root@*amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

I have tried every possible guide on the internet and still it is like this, do you have a solution for it?

- I use Windows in cmd / powershell and I also have the Linux terminal

Comment: How did it go? Still not clear what you can do?

Answer (score 3):

The error is explained in [Error: Unprotected private key file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html#troubleshoot-unprotected-key). You should set your key permissions to `400`, not `555`:

```
chmod 0400 vpnserver.pem
```

More info about this is also at:

- [I'm receiving "Permission denied (publickey)" or "Authentication failed, permission denied" errors when trying to access my EC2 instance. How do I resolve this?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-linux-fix-permission-denied-errors/)

Comment: @OF3K So what is the new error? It can't be 555 again?

Comment: I do:
```chmod 0400 vpnserver.pem```

Then I do ```ssh -i "vpnserver.pem" root@ipamazonaws.com```

And it still shows me:

```@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ @@@@@@@@@@@
@WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE! @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ @@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0555 for 'vpnserver.pem' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
Load key "vpnserver.pem": bad permissions
root@ipamazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).```

Comment: @OF3K Can your run `ls -la ./vpnserver.pem` to double check the permissions on the file?

Comment: ```-r-xr-xr-x 1 ofek ofek 1704 Feb  1 20:13 ./vpnserver.pem```

Comment: @OF3K The error message is correct. These are wrong permissions. You must be setting the permissions for different file that you use for ssh.

Comment: I do not know how and where

Comment: @OF3K Just try `chmod 0400 ./vpnserver.pem` and then `ssh -i ./vpnserver.pem root@ipamazonaws.com`. By the way, `root` is incorrect user to login, but I guess it is another issue.

Comment: Ok, I wrote:
`` `sudo ssh -i" vpnserver.pem "root @ip```
And it recorded me full of things and this:
```Please login as the user "openvpnas" rather than the user "root".```
`` `Connection to ip closed.```

What now?
* And it works.

Comment: @OF3K As I wrote that `root` is incorrect. Try with `openvpnas`. But anyway, this is new issue and not related to the key permissions. I would appreciate if you could  accept my answer. You can make new question for the new issue.

Comment: i see right now:
Permissions 0777 for 'vpnserver.pem' are too open.
@Marcin

Answer (score 1):

Note: This solution is only for Windows users.
I know OP specifically asked for Linux in his question, but we as Windows users face the same issue and look for any solution we can find when nothing works for us.

1. Select properties by right-clicking on the file name.
2. security tab > advanced
3. Remove any and every user you see there.
4. Then click on add, select principle, type your system name (in my case, Faijan Memon), and click on check name. click ok.
5. On the same page, you will only see basic permission; check the full control option. click ok
6. Now you are being redirected to the Advanced Security Settings tab. Click on the change label of owner. Type your system name (in my case, Faijan Memon) > Click on check name > click on OK > apply > OK